# Spinnaker pipeline not removing the deleted gcr images tags

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I have some query on GCR trigger tags in spinnaker pipeline. We have removed older than 30 days gcr image tags but we can still see the removed tags from the spinnaker pipeline. I have run hal deploy apply but no luck . Any one has faced this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I able to fix the issue, After I have restarted the redis pod in the spinnaker deployment.